# Pip stuck on "Running command python setup.py egg_info" - no errors.

Tags: vagrant, pip, ubuntu-16.04, vagrant-windows, taiga

I run Vagrant on Windows 10 with VirtualBox,Xenial64 ubuntu to load TaigaIO via [manual setup](http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-development.html).

At `pip install -vvv -r requirements-devel.txt` part , pip hangs forever when it tries to install `django-sampledatahelper`.

When i try to install just this package, it shows same effect: no errors, not going back to bash, just hanging on:

```
    Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/2b/fe/e8ef20ee17dcd5d4df96c36dcbcaca7a79d6a2f8dc319f4e25107e000859/django-sampledatahelper-0.4.1.tar.gz#md5=a750d769af76d3f6e5791cfeb78832b0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-sampledatahelper/)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-pZcRoU/django-sampledatahelper/setup.py) egg_info for package django-sampledatahelper
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
```

I tried fresh VM install, in virtualenv or without it, pip mirrors, removing cache and --no-cache option, xenial64 and bento/ubuntu-16.04 distros, with vagrant ssh and with Putty. Efect is the same.

Comment: Same happens for me with the package tensorforce. No matter how many things I try, it just hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is something wrong with ubuntu Xenial64 distribution AND  manual setup instructions. When i use bento/ubuntu-16.04 and setup-server.sh from [taiga-scripts](http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-alternatives.html#setup-taiga-scripts) the installation is finishing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I run -vvv command. It seemed that pip had stopped, but I waited for a couple of minutes and the package successfully installed

Comment: do you remember how long you waited for as it is stuck for me for a good while now and I'm not sure if I should just stop it

Answer (score 0):

It was still downloading the package, but slowly. The inner pip script that setting up the egg_info used neither '-i' nor '--proxy' you passed to the outer pip to accelerate the installation.

You can use a global proxy (tun/tap or vpn) or just modify the pip script to force the inner setup to download the package in an accelerated way.